# how do you execute silverlight class library?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

When execute the silverlight class library,debugging(F5) is disable.how do I test whether my class library is right?Silverlight class library is only reusable class and components from other project?
how can share   the code between the different class libraries by linking source code files between them in silverlight application??

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a demo or test project to exercise the code in your library.  typically, from within the project you want to use your library in,  you add a reference to the assembly that contains the classes that you want to use.  now, for silverlight, you are only allowed to use libraries/assemblies that are silverlight libraries--you are not allowed to use the "normal" windows class libraries.